# HP WebInspect command line interface ( CLI)

Tags: fortify

Can anyone please guide me for WebInspect CLI .

I need to invoke dynamic code analyzer:webinspect  ( for penetration testing ) from TeamCity (TC) .

Once i get to know command line invocations for WebInspect , i will write those in wrapper script and will invoke this wrapper script from TC before build step.

Thanks,
Vishal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to get access to the command line switches that drive the CLI behavior.  The First option is to invoke wi.exe with the "-?" argument and you will see explanations of each switch.  The second option is to open the WebInspect help file (WebInspect.chm) and type the following text in the search tab text entry field: "wi.exe"

The help file can be launched by hitting F1 from within the running WebInspect UI or from the Windows start menu under "All Programs > HP > HP WebInspect > Help > WebInspect"